# Binary record in a wixlib

Tags: wix, wixlib

Each one of my installers utilize certain temporary exes and dlls. In my WiX project I can put them in the Binary table. Since they're shared across all projects is it possible to put them into a wixlib? What would the syntax be.

I'm doing something similar with properties using the PropertyRef attribute. There is no corresponding BinaryRef attribute to do the same with the Binary table.

Comment: For elements that don't have a corresponding *Ref element, you can use the following workaround: Create an empty `ComponentGroup` element (which is valid WiX code) in the fragment and `ComponentGroupRef` it where you want to reference the fragment. This pulls in the whole content of the `Fragment`, not just the `ComponentGroup`.

Comment: That worked. Apparently I've been misunderstanding what the ComponentGroup element was for :(. Thanks Zett42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no corresponding BinaryRef attribute to do the same with the
>   Binary table.

For elements that don't have a corresponding *Ref element, you can use the following workaround:

- Create an empty `ComponentGroup` element (which is valid WiX code) in the fragment.
- Insert a `ComponentGroupRef` element where you want to reference the `Fragment`. This pulls in the whole content of the `Fragment`, not just the `ComponentGroup`.

Example:

```xml
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="MyBinaries"/>
    <Binary Id="Binary1" SourceFile="Files\Binary1.xyz"/>
    <Binary Id="Binary2" SourceFile="Files\Binary2.xyz"/>
</Fragment>
```

To reference MyBinaries from another .wxs file:

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="SomeComponents">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyBinaries"/>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```